# Using Server Sent Event, Client is always trying to reconnect to server, even when the client is getting the message back or not?

Tags: java, javascript, server-sent-events

As far as I know, In SSE (Server Sent Event) technique, the client tries to reconnect to server automatically whenever the connection is closed. I have been through google and actually I am getting confuse that how the SSE works.

let me know on which flow it works as below

```
client: send request "do you got any updates"
server: no updates
client: send request "do you got any updates"
server: no udates
....
......
client: send request "do you got any updates"
server: oh yes, now you got updates
```

OR

```
client: send request "do you got any updates"
server: wait a while I will let you know when I will got udates
......
.......
server: Hi you got updates, check it.
.....
.......
server: Hi again, you got updates.
```

Thanks for noticing me !!!

Comment: it more like "here's an update"... "here's another update" ... "here's another"...

Comment: Consider reading existing documentation to learn about SSE. That being said, it's basically the second alternative (with transparent reconnect *if* the connection is closed, but it should *not* be closed between each event). https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#server-sent-events

Comment: Hi @Touffy, it seems you both are referring 2nd alternative, but in my case it is the 1st alternative is working and I have been through your provided LINK. it clearly stated as you said  as below, its correct but.

**Clients will reconnect if the connection is closed;** a client can be told to stop reconnecting using the HTTP 204 No Content response code.

how a client can tell to stop reconnection using the HTTP 204 No Content response code.

Thanks..

Comment: But in my case It is the 1st alternative one, I am using javascript console to view the readyState. It repeatedly shows 0(connecting..) and 1(connection established) and then 0 - 1, 0 -1, ...

So my que is why it is reconnecting while there is no connection closing(readyState != 2).

So how I can solve it over sending request repeatedly to the server.

Comment: That can be caused by a number of reasons, none of them on the client. The event-stream server, as well as any proxy between it and the client, has to be configured to allow long-lived connections and to pass data as it becomes available. And some mobile networks might try to close inactive connections, too. Could you maybe explain your server setup, even give a link to the event-stream?

Comment: I have setup nothing at server side as I am using tomcat server and also has tested in VMware vFabric tc and Jetty server and the same problem still persists. As you told it has to be configure at server site to allow long live connection. could you let me know the configuration or setups at server site and if you have any link please share.

Thanks @Touffy

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with those servers. I cannot say more without looking at your event-stream. I can give you an example of how it *should* behave. You can open this in your browser and you'll see that it keeps adding more events without reloading: http://jsscxml.org/serverload.stream